# How to send an element multiple times in the same request in SoapUI using groovy

Tags: web-services, groovy, request, mocking, soapui

Can someone help with soap ui mock service? I want to send one part of my request n times.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:inv="http://www.testSoap.com/InvoiceService/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <inv:addInvoice>
         <invoice>
            <fkId>2</fkId>
            <dateTime>08/02/2023</dateTime>
            <status>none</status>
            <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
            <invoiceData>
               <id>1</id>
               <MPK>test</MPK>
               <RK>test</RK>
               <value>500</value>
            </invoiceData>
            <payments>
               <pid>2</pid>
               <type>xd</type>
               <valueTotal>3000</valueTotal>
            </payments>
         </invoice>
      </inv:addInvoice>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

How can I add the `invoiceData` element 3 times?  Do I change something in eclipse to do that?

```
def holder = new com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder(mockRequest.requestContent )
// get arguments 
def fkId = Integer.parseInt( holder["//fkId"] )
def dateTime = holder["//dateTime"]
def status = holder["//status"]
def id = Integer.parseInt(holder["//id"])
def MPK = holder["//MPK"] 
def RK = holder["//RK"]


def value =  Float.parseFloat(holder["//value"]) 
def pid = Integer.parseInt( holder["//pid"] )
def type = holder["//type"]

def valueTotal = Float.parseFloat(holder["//valueTotal"]) 

context.operationLogs += fkId

context.operationLogs1 += dateTime


context.operationLogs2 +=  status

context.operationLogs3 +=  id

context.operationLogs4 +=  MPK

context.operationLogs5 +=  RK

context.operationLogs6 +=  value

context.operationLogs7 +=   pid


context.operationLogs8 +=  type

context.operationLogs9 +=  valueTotal
requestContext.result1 =  fkId

requestContext.result2 = dateTime

requestContext.result3 = status 
requestContext.result4 = id
requestContext.result5 =  MPK 
requestContext.result6 = RK
requestContext.result7 = value
requestContext.result8 = pid
requestContext.result9 = type
requestContext.result10 = valueTotal
requestContext.result =  [fkId, dateTime,status,id,MPK,RK,value,pid,valueTotal ]


context.fkId = context.operationLogs.size

context.fkId = context.operationLogs1.size

context.fkId = context.operationLogs2.size

context.fkId = context.operationLogs3.size

context.fkId = context.operationLogs4.size

context.fkId = context.operationLogs5.size

context.fkId = context.operationLogs6.size

context.fkId = context.operationLogs7.size

context.fkId = context.operationLogs8.size

context.fkId = context.operationLogs9.size
```

How i can send multiple tiem this part request

```
    <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
            <invoiceData>
               <id>1</id>
               <MPK>test</MPK>
               <RK>test</RK>
               <value>500</value>
            </invoiceData>
```

i have one or more repatitons by i always send only one time
The results should be something like this using
[SupplierData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0btKi.png) elements, but when I try to add the `invoiceData` element using my Form 3 times I only get 1 `invoiceData` element and the 2nd and 3rd elements are missing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to multiuply times the same type in request soap mock service groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75500798/how-to-multiuply-times-the-same-type-in-request-soap-mock-service-groovy)

Comment: Please do not post duplicates of the same question.