# How to multiuply times the same type in request soap mock service groovy

Tags: web-services, groovy, soap, response, soapui

How to send multiply time the same type in request soap mock services

```
   <invoiceDatas>
               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
               <invoiceData>
                  <id>?</id>
                  <MPK>?</MPK>
                  <RK>?</RK>
                  <value>?</value>
               </invoiceData>
            </invoiceDatas>
```

i alwyas can send one row with this, but how to change to send for example 3 rows
cans omeone explain
in response i should have

```
 <invoiceDatas>
               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
               <invoiceData>
                  <id>?</id>
                  <MPK>?</MPK>
                  <RK>?</RK>
                  <value>?</value>
               </invoiceData>
  <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
               <invoiceData>
                  <id>?</id>
                  <MPK>?</MPK>
                  <RK>?</RK>
                  <value>?</value>
               </invoiceData>
  <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
               <invoiceData>
                  <id>?</id>
                  <MPK>?</MPK>
                  <RK>?</RK>
                  <value>?</value>
               </invoiceData>
            </invoiceDatas>
```

how i can do that ?
i knwo the best oprion it is to copy this type but i want to this dynamic by groovy

Comment: I have never done this in a mock, but here is how to [dynamically create elements in a SoapUI request](https://siking.wordpress.com/2012/01/06/dynamically-create-elements-in-a-soapui-request/). Might help you?

Answer (score 1):

I've read their documentation and I can't make heads or tails of it.  It's so vague and assumes too much for it to be of much use.  Using the manual request building process I don't think it's possible to create a repetitive expression in a Manual Request.  You'd have to manually write out say 4 or 5 invoiceData nodes each with ? and then fill those in using their Form UI.  But you couldn't create a repetition expression (forEach, each, etc) for N items using that method.

So you have to switch to Groovy script, but the documentation there is entirely unhelpful.  Using a groovy script I couldn't even get to building a simple request equivalent to what the Manual Request gave you.  I think you're best bet is to ask on their forum for help:  https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/ct-p/soapui-os-community

Beyond that I'd just cut my losses with that tool and go with another more programmer friendly library like: https://github.com/jwagenleitner/groovy-wslite

It's an older library, but I recently used it and I liked it.  It was low barrier to get coding, worked without a lot of effort, and had a very low number of dependencies.  It's not really supported and uses deprecated classes if you're working Groovy 3 or 4, but it's still quite usable and useful for SOAP.